# Error in deploying a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploy shiny app into a shiny server but getting this error:

```
Error: HTTP 400
POST https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/
Validation Error
```

After writing in the console:

```
    shinyapps::deployApp("C:\\Users\\Shiny App")
```

All the installation went ok, I got Rtools available as well, I'm set to be in the working directory... where is the problem?

Comment: Did you create a Login Token and configure your rsconnect like mentioned on http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html ?

Comment: Yes, i have done step by step what that article says and still get the error...

Answer (score 4):

Make sure there are no spaces in the last snippet of that "link to your app" path name, it somehow causes an error.

For example:

This snippet of code caused me a problem.

```
shinyapps::deployApp('C:/Users/InfiniteFlash/Desktop/App Name')
```

but this one doesn't

```
shinyapps::deployApp('C:/Users/InfiniteFlash/Desktop/App_Name')
```

Avoiding spaces apparently allows the app to deploy.